# expectation of product between constant

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

Say $w_i$ is each constant, $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and independent of $w_i$, how can one derive the equation $\displaystyle E[(\Sigma_{i=1}^D w_i \epsilon_i)^2]= \Sigma_{i=1}^{D}w_i^2\sigma^2$ ? There's no other assumption on $w_i$

Some of my thought:

I know we can get $E[\epsilon_i^2]=\sigma^2$ and can lead to $E[(\Sigma_{i=1}^D w_i \epsilon_i)^2]=E[\Sigma_{i=1}^{D}w_i)^2] \sigma^2$, but how to make the square be with each $w_i$ instead of outside the sum?

Since $E[\Sigma_{i=1}^{D}w_i)^2] \sigma^2 = E[w_1 + w_2 + ... +w_D)^2]\sigma^2 = E[w_1^2 + w_2^2 + ... +w_D^2 + 2w_1w_2 + 2w_1w_3 + ... + 2 w_{D-1}w_D]\sigma^2$, when will the expectation between those $w_i$ become zero? I learned constant's expectation will just be a constant but not necessarily zero.

Comment: What you wrote here is definitely wrong; I guess you should have $\epsilon_i$ instead of $\epsilon$; what is the background here? Where did you see this problem?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I feel each $\epsilon_i$ is independent so the idea is basically similar ? it's from bishop's machine learning and pattern recognition's exercise 3.4.

Comment: So please correct to question and write it down properly. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Any idea?

Comment: Expectation is linear, and in general you cannot first take the expectation inside a square (can be seen by Jensen's inequality). If you do not know the trick, you may try to expand the whole square of the sum, just a little bit tedious but still manageable. A better trick will be considering $E[X^2] = Var[X] + E[X]^2$ to deal with it.

Comment: Hint $E(\epsilon_i\epsilon_j)=0$.